# Equivalent of openSuse "zypper ps" on other distros?

Tags: linux, centos, opensuse

I love how "zypper ps" in openSuse 11.2 tells you which currently running processes need to be restarted after an update with "zypper update".

How can I do this with other distros, in particular CentOS?

Answer (score 6):

A generic solution would be:

```
lsof | grep deleted
```

This gives a list of files which are deleted, but still referenced by processes.

FYI, internally, the system already replaced the filename, hence it points to the new data.
The old data blocks still exist at the disk until the remaining applications have closed the file.

Answer (score 4):

I can see this is a very old post, but nevertheless here's answer for at least Fedora:

```
yum install yum-plugin-ps
```

After installation yum will tell you which processes need restart after upgrading packages.

Answer (score 4):

In Debian you can use `checkrestart` from the [`debian-goodies` package](http://packages.debian.org/stable/debian-goodies).

Answer (score 2):

yum has no option to do this. and i don't know about a plugin which could this. but when you have time and fun with scripting, it should be possible to do it with yum commands.

- get package update list
- get whatprovides for this list
- check the whatprovides list against your running processes
- for every match print out a line to restart the service

this is just a rough outline of the script, but should do the same as `zypper ps`.

Answer (score 2):

For Fedora/CentOS/RHEL the command `yum ps` doesn't actually exist. Instead look at `needs-restarting` which is provided by the `yum-utils` package. This looks like it will provide the information you're wanting.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this. I tried this and it seems to work.

Comment: Unfortunately `needs-restarting` is only included in `yum-utils` for RHEL >= 6, so I'm out of luck on my RHEL 5 boxes.